# How much scaffolding is currently on Neuschwanstein Castle?

Tags: germany, castles, bavaria

I will be in Munich for 2-3 days in a couple of weeks.

I am trying to determine if it is worth taking the time to go out to Neuschwanstein Castle, given both the 4+ hours round trip travel time and the scaffolding.

Comment: Just a thought: Is this question too localized? It will be obsolete almost immediately (in June!).  Can it perhaps be re-phrased to make it less localized?  "When will renovation be completed on Neuschwanstein Castle?" or somesuch?

Comment: @Flimzy: I agree it's kind of localized, but still a valid question, if one is interested in e.g. taking photos of the castle. Most photos you'd find online won't probably be dated or recent enough to represent the current state of the building. So I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @mindcorrosive: I think it's a valid question, too (Or I'd have VTCed), I just think it can be made more general and less localized, while still providing the relevant information.

Comment: That seems very reasonable. I am not sure how editing works, so I will leave that to others.

Comment: I was so disappointed when I was finally able to get to Füssen and found the castle under scaffolding. It is also vitally important to get tickets early. We were in line at 12 and a the first tour available was at 17:30.

Comment: I'm removing the date from this question and leaving "currently". With the date it is too localized, but if people update it from time to time it will remain a great question.

Comment: @hippietrail: Good idea. Now, 4 months later, it's actually clear that this is a *perfect* long tail Travel SE question (see view count)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, there is unfortunately a lot of scaffolding going on in Neuschwanstein. I quote the official homepage:

> Restoration works at the western and northern façade
>
> Because of restoration works the western and northern façade of
>   Neuschwanstein Castle will be scaffolded until the end of 2012.
>
> We apologize for any inconveniences.
>
> The guided tours in the castle are not affected by the works.

You can have a look by yourself using one of these two webcams. Unfortunately it is night now, so you won't see a lot ;)

http://allgaeu-cam.de/wetter/schloss-neuschwanstein.html

http://www.schwangau.de/webcams-230.html

[image]